# Prove that the $\tau_{i, j}$ are invertible and form a basis for $\mathcal{L}(V)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ have basis $\mathcal{B} = \{v_{1}, \dots, v_{n}\}$ and asume that the base field $F$ for $V$ has characteristic 0. Suppose that for each $1 \leq i, j \leq n$ we define $\tau_{i, j} \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ by
>
> $$
> \tau_{i, j}(v_{k}) =
> \left\{ \begin{array}{}
> v_{k} & \mbox{if}
> & k \neq i \\
> v_{i} + v_{j} & \mbox{if} & k=i
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
>
> Prove that the $\tau_{i, j}$ are invertible and form a basis for $\mathcal{L}(V)$.

I have some ideas as:

Suppose that $\tau_{i, j}$ form a basis for $\text{Im}(V)$, then $\text{Im}(V) = \alpha_{1}\tau(v_{1}), \dots, \alpha_{n}\tau(v_{n})$. We know that $\tau$ is surjective iff $\text{Im}(\tau) = V$ and that $\tau$ is injective iff $\text{Ker}(\tau) = \{0\}$...

I'm having a bad time with this, any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: An injective linear transformation maps a linearly independent set to a linearly independent set. You obtain a similar characterization if you replace injective with surjective and linearly independent with spanning set. But on finite dimensional spaces: an injective linear map is actually surjective.

Let $v \in V$, then $v = \sum_{s=1}^{n}c_{s}v_{s}$. Then $\tau_{i,j}(v) = v + c_{i}v_{j}$. Hence, $\tau_{i,j}(v) = 0 \iff -c_{i}v_{j} = v$, which if $c_{i} = 0$, then $v =0$, and if $c_{i} \neq 0$, then we get a contradiction to linearly independence of $v_{i}$.  Hence, $c_{s} = 0$ for all $s$. Hence, $v =0$ and we have shown that $\tau_{i,j}$ is injective.